# Pinned dynamic column in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am following this [url](https://stackblitz.com/angular/kooxxyvddeqb?file=app%2Ftable-sticky-columns-example.html). I want to Fixed/pinned first 2 column ( name & no.) I dont know how to use sticky property here because all my columns are dynamic.

This is my html code for dynamic columns:

```
< ng-container [matColumnDef]="col" *ngFor="let col of displayedColumns" >

< mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{ col }} < /mat-header-cell>

< mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element[col] }}  < /mat-cell>
< /ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using index value.

```
<ng-container [matColumnDef]="col" *ngFor="let col of displayedColumns; let i = index;">

<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef *ngIf="i==0 || i ==1"> {{ col }} </mat-header-cell>

<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element[col] }}  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: So yes using `index` or `first` provides the ability to know the 1st column in a dynamic layout. _However_ this doesn't still answer how to apply the `sticky` directive. It needs to be placed on the `ng-container` that also contains `matColumnDef` I tried `sticky="i==0"` and `sticky="first"` but it's not working correctly and sticking multiple columns.